# Given weighted points on a plane, find locations for U squares such that the total enclosed weight would be maximized

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I'm faced with the following problem:

**Given**

- A set of points on an Euclidean plane, each point P(x,y,w) has coordinates and an associated positive weight.
- A set of U squares, all having the same size length L.

**Goal:**

- Assign (find locations for) the squares such that the total points' weight enclosed within all the squares would be maximized.

**Notes:**

- The squares should be axis-parallel
- The squares may overlap, but the enclosed weights won't be counted more than once.

I'm looking for an *optimal assignment*.

**My questions:**

- Is this a known problem (Does it has a name? Has it been explored before?).
- Any ideas how to approach it?

(I may be expected to mention what have I tried. Since I'm looking for an *optimal* assignment, my heuristic ideas are not really relevant. At this point I have no idea how to find the optimal assignment).

Comment: Please clarify your definition of a U square. 

And by enclosed within all the squares, you don't mean that the points should be in the plane of the square, but contained within some set of boxes, where each side is made from these axis parallel squares, or intersect with other such boxes?

Comment: @RobertJørgensgaardEngdahl: U is the number of the equally-sized squares I want to find optimal locations for. The squares are on the same plane as the points (this is a 2D problem).

Comment: Can you add an image of what the program is supposed to do in 2D?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: The weights are in the range (0,1] and belongs to a finite set (about 20 values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a geometric special case of the weighted [maximum coverage problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem). The general MCP is NP-hard, and I suspect that this special case is as well, though unlike the general case, it probably has an efficient polynomial-time approximation scheme. You want an optimal solution, however, so the first thing that I would recommend is to feed the integer linear programming formulation in the linked Wikipedia article to an LP solver.

```
maximize sum_j (w_j * y_j)
subject to
for all i, sum_i x_i <= U
for all j, sum_{i : j in S_i} x_i - y_j >= 0
for all i, x_i in {0, 1}
for all j, 0 <= y_j <= 1
```

The weight `w_j` of each point `j` is given, and the sets `S_i` are all possibilities for covering points with a width `L` square. The meaning of `x_i` is whether set `S_i` is chosen. The meaning of `y_j` is whether point `j` is covered. The simplest cubic algorithm for constructing the `S_i`s is to enumerate all squares whose lower left vertex has x coordinate equal to that of some point and y coordinate equal to that of some (possibly other) point, since every other square can be slid up and/or to the right without sacrificing coverage.

Comment: Thanks David. Do you have by chance a reference to a more extensive description of a method for constructing S_i? (Which data structures to use, etc.)

Comment: @LiorKogan I don't have a reference handy, since I just thought it up. In slightly more detail, the algorithm is to gather and sort the x-coordinates of the points, gather and sort the y-coordinates of the points, for x in the x-coordinates, for y in the y-coordinates, scan through the other points to see which belong to the square of width L whose left side has x-coordinate x and whose bottom side has y-coordinate y. I suspect that it would be counterproductive to use data structures here, given that solving the integer program will take a while.